# Can one think of "let" and other Rust idioms in terms of assembly?

Tags: rust

When writing in C, it's straightforward to reason about how assignments will look like after compilation. I know Rust is a higher level language that uses functional features, but since it's referred to as a "system language" I wonder if that's possible in Rust too.

For example, I want to loop through an array of integers and calculate the biggest product of 3 adjacent numbers:

```c
unsigned int a[10] = {4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 0, 7, 4, 9, 2};
unsigned int i, p=1, max=0;
for(i=0; i<8; i++, p=1) {
    p = a[i] * a[i+1] * a[i+2];
    if(p>max) max = p;
}
```

The equivalent Rust code could look like this (not sure if this is the idiomatic way):

```
let a = [4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 0, 7, 4, 9, 2];
let mut max = 0;
for i in 0..8 {
    let p = a[i] * a[i + 1] * a[i + 2];
    if p > max {
        max = p;
    }
}
```

In C, `p` is a variable that is defined before the loop and is assigned a new value every time; in Rust on the other hand, `let p` is used within the loop, which is confusing to think about in a procedural way.

Is C *closer* to assembly code? Or is it possible to reason about Rust just as well?

Comment: You can put `int p = ...` inside the loop in C as well.

Comment: Since I am quite new to programming and only coded in ANSI C so far, I didn't know that. My question still stands though, since in C you have a way to be more explicit.

Comment: *it's straightforward to reason about how assignments will look like after compilation* — hahahaha, no it's *not*. Maybe in a world without optimizing compilers, sure, but not for any modern C.

Comment: The answer to your question is **Yes, you can think of “let” and other Rust idioms in terms of assembly**. Now that you know this, how does it help you?

Comment: FWIW, I'd write the Rust code as `let max = a[..5].windows(3).map(|w| w.iter().product()).max().unwrap_or(0);` which should be equally as efficient (potentially more or less so).

Comment: You can always get the assembly output of a trivial Rust program to find out *exactly* how it gets translated.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I guess it's a matter of practicing and getting used to the language.

Comment: `0..7` is still wrong, as it doesn't include `7`. You either mean `0..8` or `0..=7`. If you meant the whole array, my example is even easier to write: `let max = a.windows(3).map(|w| w.iter().product()).max().unwrap_or(0);`

Comment: You can put `int p = ...` inside the loop even in ANSI C, since it is at the beginning of a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: It is perfectly possible to reason about Rust code in terms of assembly. However, you need to be familiar with the safety features and high-level abstractions that it offers which C does not.

---

If you want to think about C and Rust in terms of assembly the first point to consider is *which C compiler do you use?*

GCC and Clang/LLVM emit vastly different assembly. While the assembly generated by GCC is [pretty close to the C code](https://godbolt.org/g/9SxLsP), Clang/LLVM seems to [unroll the loop in the original example](https://godbolt.org/g/Dj2PKa). (This opens the question: "which is closer to assembly - C or C?")

Rust uses LLVM too, so let's compare it to Clang. This is part of the Clang assembly:

```
  imul esi, eax
  mov edx, dword ptr [rdi + 20]
  imul esi, edx
  cmp esi, ecx
  cmovbe esi, ecx
```

I'm not an expert on assembly, but this should be one iteration of the unrolled loop. There is access to the indexed array, a multiplication, and a check that replaces the current maximum value.

The corresponding snippet of [Rust assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/Fwi8XZ) looks like this:

```
  cmp r8, 5
  je .LBB0_16
  imul eax, edx
  mov esi, dword ptr [rdi + 20]
  imul eax, esi
  cmp eax, ecx
  cmovbe eax, ecx
```

The only difference is that some registers are used differently and that there is a comparison and conditional jump in the beginning. This is the bounds check performed by Rust when indexing into `a`. You don't have that in C - if the array is too small, anything can happen. In Rust you get a clear panic, but it comes at a small cost (runtime check = more instructions).

If this is additional cost is a problem, there is an escape hatch: unsafe code.

```
p = unsafe {*a.as_ptr().offset(i) * *a.as_ptr().offset(i+1) * *a.as_ptr().offset(i+2)};
```

With this change we [get assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/aoUXsa) that is mostly similar to the C assembly, but we lose part of Rust's safety.

---

All that said, there is not really an assembly equivalent to Rust's `let x =` or C's `int x =`. These idioms are higher level abstractions that are saying "I want to have a new local variable". It is up to the compiler to decide what to make of that. It can use a memory location or an available register, whichever is more suitable, but the CPU does not care about variables.